# SVN force repository format

Tags: svn, sshfs

We use svn version 1.5.1 (r32289) at work, I've got version 1.6.6 (r40053) on my OS X machine. I'm using [sshfs](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html) to mount a directory on our development server, where I thought I could use svn from my machine to "save" another connection to dev server. But, anytime I touch the repository with svn 1.6.6 (even `svn up`), I (and my colleagues) get the following error when trying to handle svn from development/live machine:

> svn: This client is too old to work with working copy '.'.  You need to get a newer Subversion client, or to downgrade this working copy. See http://subversion.tigris.org/faq.html#working-copy-format-change for details.

Using script provided on the page mentioned in error message fixes the problem, but:

**Is there a way to specify format that svn should use/force when handling a repository?**

I'm fine with creating alias for svn commands (in the case I'd need to add a parameter to every svn command).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, hopefully you are not using the file:// protocol to do this: [Choosing a Server Configuration: Recommendations](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.choosing.html).

The other thing to pay attention to is that the working copy format will often change between 1.**X** versions (but not 1.X.**Y** versions).

Once you have used a newer SVN tool that updates the working copy, you need to update all of your client tools to be using the same SVN version (or run the script to down-convert after each newer tool access).

You *can* use newer client versions while still using an older SVN database format (though not sure how that plays out when using file://?).

So to answer your question **Is there a way to specify format that svn should use/force when handling a repository?**

It is not the repository that is the problem, but the working copy. If possible, just update the clients at work. Otherwise, stop using 1.6.6 clients anywhere else.

Comment: Thank you for answer and recommendations.

Comment: And no, we're not using `file:///` protocol... I didn't even knew one could/would :)